# Number of mapped views to a shared memory on Windows

Tags: windows, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

Is there a way to check how many views have been mapped on to a memory mapped file on Windows?

Something like the equivalent of `shmctl(... ,IPC_STAT,...)` on Linux?

Comment: Someone marked this -1. Would love to hear the reason. Was the question too vague? Was it not formulated correctly? Was it ambiguous? Not enough detail? How can I improve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the number of shared memory mapped file views (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108286/accessing-the-number-of-shared-memory-mapped-file-views-windows)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need to access the number of shared views. So I created this question: [Accessing the number of shared memory mapped file views (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108286/accessing-the-number-of-shared-memory-mapped-file-views-windows)

You may find a solution that suits your needs there.

---

As per [Scath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1753960/scath) comment, I am going to add here the proposed solution, although merit should go to [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) and [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm). Making use of `NtQueryObject` call one can access the HandleCount (although it may not be 100% reliable):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

typedef NTSTATUS (__stdcall *NtQueryObjectFuncPointer) (
            HANDLE                   Handle,
            OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS ObjectInformationClass,
            PVOID                    ObjectInformation,
            ULONG                    ObjectInformationLength,
            PULONG                   ReturnLength);

int main(void)
{
    _PUBLIC_OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION pobi;
    ULONG rLen;

    // Create the memory mapped file (in system pagefile) (better in global namespace
    // but needs SeCreateGlobalPrivilege privilege)
    HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE|SEC_COMMIT,
                  0, 1, "Local\\UniqueShareName");

    // Get the NtQUeryObject function pointer and then the handle basic information
    NtQueryObjectFuncPointer _NtQueryObject = (NtQueryObjectFuncPointer)GetProcAddress(
            GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryObject");

    _NtQueryObject(hMap, ObjectBasicInformation, (PVOID)&pobi, (ULONG)sizeof(pobi), &rLen);

    // Check limit
    if (pobi.HandleCount > 4) {
        printf("Limit exceeded: %ld > 4\n", pobi.HandleCount);
        exit(1);
    }
    //...
    Sleep(30000);
}
```

Comment: @Scath Thanks for the clarification, I hope now the answer to be "correct"