# Accessing the number of shared memory mapped file views (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory-mapped-files

I am developing a multi-platform C++ application (mainly Windows and Linux), now I face the need to be able to limit the maximum number of instances of the application that may run at the same time (in the same machine).

I have already a shared memory module that uses:

- Linux: System V shared memory (shmget(), shmat()...)
- Windows: Memory mapped files (CreateFileMapping(), OpenFileMapping(), MapViewOfFile(),...)

In linux I can easily control the number of instances running with this kind of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct shmid_ds shm;
    int shmId;
    key_t shmKey = 123456; // A unique key...

    // Allocating 1 byte shared memory segment
    // open it if already existent and rw user permission
    shmId = shmget(shmKey, 1, IPC_CREAT|0x0180);

    // Attach to the shared memory segment
    shmat(shmId, (char *) 0, SHM_RDONLY);

    // Get the number of attached "clients"
    shmctl(shmId, IPC_STAT, &shm);

    // Check limit
    if (shm.shm_nattch > 4) {
        printf("Limit exceeded: %ld > 4\n", shm.shm_nattch);
        exit(1);
    }

    //...
    sleep(30);
}
```

The nice thing of this code is that when the application is killed or crashes the system takes care decrementing the number of attached clients.

Now my question is, **how to implement this in Windows?** (using memory mapped files). The *"same"* code translated to Windows memory mapped files would be (more or less):

```
void functionName(void)
{
    // Create the memory mapped file (in system pagefile)
    HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE|SEC_COMMIT,
                  0, 1, "Global\\UniqueShareName");

    // Map the previous memory mapped file into the address space
    char *addr = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

    // How can I check now the number of views mapped?
}
```

I have been searching for quite some time and I cannot find how to get **the number of opened views**.

From the [CreateFileMapping function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Mapped views of a file mapping object maintain **internal references** to
>   the object, and a file mapping object does not close until all
>   references to it are released. Therefore, to fully close a file
>   mapping object, an application must unmap all mapped views of the file
>   mapping object by calling UnmapViewOfFile and close the file mapping
>   object handle by calling CloseHandle. These functions can be called in
>   any order.

From [UnmapViewOfFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366882(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Unmapping a mapped view of a file invalidates the range occupied by
>   the view in the address space of the process and makes the range
>   available for other allocations. It removes the working set entry for
>   each unmapped virtual page that was part of the working set of the
>   process and reduces the working set size of the process. **It also
>   decrements the share count of the corresponding physical page**.

But I cannot get that **shared count**, and the only stackoverflow question regarding this matter (that I have found) is unanswered: [Number of mapped views to a shared memory on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593517/number-of-mapped-views-to-a-shared-memory-on-windows)

I would really appreciate if anybody could help me with this.

---

### Solution

(**Note:** Although may not be 100% reliable, see the comments section)

From the comments of [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm) and [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) (Thanks!) I am able to solve the question with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

typedef NTSTATUS (__stdcall *NtQueryObjectFuncPointer) (
            HANDLE                   Handle,
            OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS ObjectInformationClass,
            PVOID                    ObjectInformation,
            ULONG                    ObjectInformationLength,
            PULONG                   ReturnLength);

int main(void)
{
    _PUBLIC_OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION pobi;
    ULONG rLen;

    // Create the memory mapped file (in system pagefile) (better in global namespace
    // but needs SeCreateGlobalPrivilege privilege)
    HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE|SEC_COMMIT,
                  0, 1, "Local\\UniqueShareName");

    // Get the NtQUeryObject function pointer and then the handle basic information
    NtQueryObjectFuncPointer _NtQueryObject = (NtQueryObjectFuncPointer)GetProcAddress(
            GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryObject");

    _NtQueryObject(hMap, ObjectBasicInformation, (PVOID)&pobi, (ULONG)sizeof(pobi), &rLen);

    // Check limit
    if (pobi.HandleCount > 4) {
        printf("Limit exceeded: %ld > 4\n", pobi.HandleCount);
        exit(1);
    }
    //...
    Sleep(30000);
}
```

But to be correct I should be using the Global kernel namespace, which needs a privilege (SeCreateGlobalPrivilege). So at the end I may resort to the named pipe solution (very nice and neat).

Comment: for what you use section object (and map it), if you want know only handle count of object ? why say not event object ? handle count of kernel object get possible

Comment: In a kernel debugger you can see the `NumberOfMappedViews` in the control area of a Section object, but I don't think there's an NT API to query that information. `QueryWorkingSetEx` can query the number of processes sharing a page, given a virtual address, but it's limited to 7. Anyway, I don't think this is the way to go. You could use a named pipe and limit the number of instances, which would be more reliable than using a semaphore (i.e. processes can crash or get terminated without releasing the semaphore).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - this is not exactly true. we can call [`NtQueryObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryobject) with `ObjectInformation` and check `HandleCount` of [`OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_public_object_basic_information).

Comment: instead of using semaphore, can use variable in pe [shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/section-specify-section-attributes) section, but if process will be terminated externally - nobody decrement this variable

Comment: @RbMm The reason to use memory mapped files, was to solve the "problem" in a similar way in both platforms (Windows and Linux). But at the end I guess I will go with the named pipe route. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a slightly skeptical of the Section handle-count solution. Handles can be duplicated, at least temporarily (so a process might exit due to a silly race condition), and I haven't made an extensive study of the handle count of objects over their lifetime in practical application. It should be ok though, and RbMm will probably tell me there's no reason to worry. Note that if your application runs as an administrator, then SeCreateGlobalPrivilege is present and default enabled.

Comment: @eryksun you are right, but the application is normally run without administrator privileges.

Comment: @eryksun - agree that handle-count solution have problems and raise condition. i simply note that possible get handle count. however this is also can be under question. say before win8 `PointerCount` (member of `OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION`) show real pointer (reference) count to object. but now this already not true. possible the same be with `HandleCount` too :)

Comment: if you want use global namespace possible use (undocumented) `"Global\\Restricted\\somenape"` path. here (under `Restricted` subfolder) you not need `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` and Everyone have access to this place for write. low integrity processes too

Comment: with `QueryWorkingSetEx` i think problem not in limit to 7 `ShareCount` information 9usual this is enough, you want only 4), but page can be not in process working set at all

Comment: @RbMm You're really a connoisseur in the matter!  I'm concerned about how "reliable" the memory mapped solution is. But I will use the `Global\\Restricted\\` in another shared memory limitation I had. Thanks!

Comment: despite `Restricted` subfolder (`\BaseNamedObjects\Restricted`) undocumented, but it exist currently in all windows versions and have almost the same access as `\BaseNamedObjects`, except `S-1-5-12` (`Restricted`) have full access to it, when to `BaseNamedObjects` it have only `DIRECTORY_TRAVERSE` access. but this is unrelated i think.

Comment: @RbMm, yes, a page could become invalid even if it was just accessed, and it could be invalid in any of the other processes, so it's generally unreliable to look at the share count on a page for this use case. I was looking at the problem in terms of providing the only view on this information that NT deems of interest to user mode. Even if the pages are always locked via `VirtualLock`, it's still of limited use since it's only a 3-bit counter up to 7 processes.

Comment: That should have been "page is always locked", not "pages". There's no point in locking more than the first page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as noted eryksun, most reliable way for do this - use [`CreateNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx) function. we can use `nMaxInstances` parameter - *The maximum number of instances that can be created for this pipe.* in next way. every instances of the application on start try create pipe instance. if this is ok - we can run, otherwise the limit is reached.

code can be next:

```
BOOL IsLimitReached(ULONG MaxCount)
{
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), &sd, FALSE };

    HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\<some pipe>", 
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_READMODE_BYTE, MaxCount, 0, 0, 0, &sa);

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ULONG dwError = GetLastError();

        if (dwError != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
        {
            // handle error 
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

and use, say for N instances

```
    if (!IsLimitReached(N))
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, L"running..",0,0);
    }
```

Comment: This could also be done with a named Job that's configured with an active-process limit and silent breakaway for child Processes. To avoid polling for the Job to be ready, opening the Job can be gated with a named manual-reset Event. For example, create the Event, and if the last error is not already-exists, create and configure the Job, assign the current Process, and set the Event. Otherwise wait for the Event to be set, open the Job, and assign the current Process. Exit if the latter fails with not-enough-quota. When all Processes terminate, then the Event and Job are destroyed.

Comment: As always, the caveat with Job objects is that prior to Windows 8 they won't always work because a process can only be assigned to a single Job. Assigning to this Job will fail if the process is already in a Job. For example, the task scheduler always executes a task in a Job. The best you can do in this case is try to respawn the current process to break away from the Job. However, a Job has to be configured to allow this. This is extremely painful and annoying, so much so that Microsoft should have backported nested Job support to Vista.

Comment: @eryksun - think not need any separate event for job solution. `CreateJobObject` have open_if logic - `Creates or opens a job object`. so all processes call `CreateJobObject`, then all call `SetInformationJobObject` with `JobObjectBasicLimitInformation` (for set `ActiveProcessLimit` and `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` and finally try assign self to job. but think solution with pipe better and have no side effects

Comment: Although this answer does not solve the *Accessing the number of shared memory mapped file views (Windows)* exactly. I marked it as the solution, because is the solution I am going to use. I am not a stack overflow expert, should I change the question title?

Comment: @MarcosG., I think it's fine to leave the question title as is. RbMm could include an explicit statement that this is a workaround for the problem as framed since it's not possible to query the number of times a section has been mapped in Windows (even though the kernel does track this information by necessity).